# Laravel hosting error

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel for my php project everything worked fine in devlopment but during hosting since i wasen't given a shell access on server so i could not create a symlink . so i moved the contents of public folder to root and changed index.php accordingly . but i have been getting this error

```
Warning: chdir() [function.chdir]: No such file or directory (errno 2)  
in /home/saarorgi/public_html/paths.php on line 62

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in 
/home/saarorgi/public_html/laravel/laravel.php on line 1

You can check the link -> saar.org.in
```

please reply fast it really urgent

Comment: Did u check all the paths inside the path.php file, make sure that they are given the correct path

Answer (score 1):

1.Copy  files  on Laravel's  public folder into a folder you want to put them on public_html.

2.Copy Laravel's other folders anywhere your want to put them. Rename if you wanted.

3.Open index.php on your public folder with text editor , and change "require '`../paths.php';`" to fit your directory structure.

4.Open paths.php  with text editor, and change  "`path['xxxx'] = 'xxxxx';`" format lines to fit your directory structure.

5.Don't forget set permition for your 'storage' directory.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure your PHP version is same or better than the Laravel requirement, this has happened to me long time ago.

Answer (score -1):

Check your PHP version >= 5.4, this one:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in 
/home/saarorgi/public_html/laravel/laravel.php on line 1
```

Belongs to that.

Answer (score -1):

This type of error usually occurs due PHP version issue. Update to PHP 7, the newest version of PHP. Moreover,you may need to contact your hosting provider if the error remains because many hosting provider keep few restrictions, So you can request them to allow access.